Why is AdS-boundary considered timelike?
I was wondering why the conformal boundary of (compactified) AdS is said to be timelike. Consider the conformal compactification of AdS spacetime with metric
$$g = (- dt^2 + dx^2 + \sin^2 x \ d\Omega^2 ) \quad , \qquad x \in (0,\pi/2]$$
A timelike surface is one, where every tangent vector is everywhere timelike. Since the conformal boundary is a 3D hypersurface defined by $\{ x = \pi/2 \}$, I can choose e.g. the curve $c : s \longmapsto c(s) = \big(\text{const}, \tfrac{\pi}{2}, \theta(s), \varphi(s) \big)$
with tangent
$$\dot{c}(s) = \big(0, 0, \dot{\theta}(s), \dot{\varphi}(s) \big)$$
and length
$$g_{ij} \dot{c}^i \dot{c}^j = \dot{\theta}^2(s) + \sin^2 \theta(s) \ \dot{\varphi}^2(s) > 0$$
which is spacelike. But as I understand it, every tangent on the conformal boundary should be timelike. So what am I missing here?

You have the incorrect definition. Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth semi-Riemannian manifold and let $\Sigma\subset M$ be a hyper surface, i.e., a codimension one embedded submanifold. We say that $\Sigma$ is timelike if its normal vector is spacelike. Please check the book "Spacetime and geometry" by Sean Carroll as a reference for this.
Since the AdS boundary is a level set $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, its normal convector is $dx$. Therefore the normal vector is $$n^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}(dx)_\nu = g^{\mu x}.$$
The metric is $$g = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &.1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \sin^2 x\ \gamma_{AB}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\gamma$ is the $S^{2}$ round metric. In that case the inverse metric has $g^{\mu x} = \delta^{\mu x}$. As such the normal vector is indeed $\partial_x$ which is obviously spacelike. Therefore the AdS boundary is timelike.
In fact, in global AdS the boundary is the Lorentzian cylinder $\mathbb{R}\times S^2$, whereas in the Poincaré patch the boundary is the plane $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$, both of which are standard Lorentzian manifolds containing both timelike, spacelike and null tangent vectors.

Ah I see. I should be more careful with the definitions next time. Thank you!
